# Sites using nvd3.js for visualizations

Tags: website, javascript, jquery, data-visualization

I've recently started using a free javascript library called "NVD3.js" to build "interactive visualizations" for our commercial web applications. I'm thinking of applying it to our public web sites as well but haven't started, yet.

I was wondering if anyone is using NVD3.js to generate visualizations for their own public web sites.

If so what are the benefits in using NVD3.

Can anyone suggest me some sites that use NVD3 so I can look into it myself.

Note: I posted this question in stackoverflow.com and they suggested me this site.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089211/sites-using-nvd3-js-for-visualizations#comment21228140_15089211